# jQuery Defining Custom Functions

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I'm trying to a define my own function in jQuery to condense my js file, but I seem to be unable to shorten these two lines. Below is:

*My function

*What it looks like with the function

*What the original code looks like without the function

```
var AddContent = function(content) {
    $(#log li:last).remove();
    $(#log).append(content);
};


    $('.object').click(function(){
        AddContent('<li>content1</li>');
    });



    $('.object').click(function(){
        $('#log li:last').remove();
        $('#log').append('<li>content1</li>');
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Help!

Comment: need quotes around your selectors

Answer (score 2):

In your new function `AddContent` -- you need to put quote around the selectors.

I.e.

```
var AddContent = function(content) {
    $(#log li:last).remove();
    $(#log).append(content);
};
```

Should be

```
var AddContent = function(content) {
    $('#log li:last').remove();
    $('#log').append(content);
};
```

Comment: Also, you may want to tryout the replaceWith function instead of remove/add  http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: Your welcome -- You could also just "Accept Answer" instead of leaving a comment :-)